# Delete remote branches when local branch is deleted

Tags: git

I am new to Git, and I deleted a variety of my git branches in my local repository. I pushed all my changes to the remote, but the remote branches are still there.

Do I have to manually delete the remote branches now as well, or can I somehow keep them in sync so all deleted branches can be removed on the remote as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+delete+branch+local+remote